# DCOMを使わないで、同じサーバ―内でVB6のCOMからCreateObjectで外部EXEの関数を呼び出すことはできるのでしょうか？

Tags: com, vb6

DCOMを使わないで、同じサーバ―内でVB6のCOMからCreateObjectで外部EXEの関数を呼び出すことはできるのでしょうか？

現在は、DCOMの構成の「場所」で「次のコンピューター上でアプリケーションを実行する」にチェックを入れて、別EXEサーバ―のIPアドレスを指定しています。
別EXE用サーバ―に「Test.exe」が置いてあります。

■現在のセットアップ方法
1.別EXEサーバ―で下記を実行
C:/TEST.exe /regserver

2.APサーバーで下記を実行
CLIREG32.EXE .\TEST.VBR -d -q -s 別EXE用サーバ―IPアドレス -t .\TEST.TLB

今は上記の設定を行ってTEST.EXEのCreateObjectが実行出来ている状態です。

これを同じAPサーバー上に、「C:/TEST.exe」を移動して、TEST.exeのCalc()というFunctionを呼び出したいです。
EXEはActiveXだと思います。

(イメージ)
Set test = CreateObject("TEST.clsCalc")
ret = test.Calc()

APサーバーに「C:/TEST.exe」を配置して、下記の様にレジストリ登録しました。
C:/TEST.exe /regserver

その上で、下記の部分を動かしてみましたが、TEST.exeは呼び出されていないように見えます。
Set test = CreateObject("TEST.clsCalc")
ret = test.Calc()

Comment: そのくらいの作業だと、実際にやってみるとか、もう少し細かく呼び出し側をデバッガでステップ実行させても良いのでは？ その結果何も動作していないように見えるとか、エラー通知/エラーメッセージ表示やイベントログ記録があるとか、それらの詳細を質問に追記した方が助言・回答が付きやすいと思われます。

Comment: ちなみにDCOMで別サーバーを呼び出していたものを同じサーバー内に切り替えるとかの作業ではなく、VB6からWord/Excel/Outlook等を呼び出していれば、それは外部EXEの関数を呼び出していることになります。他には自分で作る例などの記事もあります。[カンタンOLEサーバー （ActiveX EXE)](http://www.surveytec.com/prog/vb/kouza2/chap1.html), [他のアプリケーションの起動（API関数,OLE,DDE）](http://basic.my.coocan.jp/vba/vba4.htm)

Comment: カンタンOLEサーバーの方のリンクがイメージに近いです。サンプルプログラムをダウンロードして、「CliTest.vbp」を開いて、実行後に「Command1」ボタンを押しましたが、「ActiveXコンポーネントはオブジェクトを作成できません。」とエラーになります。私のプログラムもこれと同じエラーになります。「SvrTest.exe」をレジストリ登録するような手順は記載がありませんが、その必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: また、上記サンプルの「SvrTest.exe」を単独でダブルクリックで実行してもエラーになりました。「予期せぬエラーが発生しました。終了します。」端末はWin10Proです。

Comment: そう言えば、COMコンポーネントの登録のためには、こうした記事が書かれた当時には存在しなかった条件として、VisualStudioIDEや該当プログラムを管理者モードや管理者として実行で起動する必要があります。コンパイルやレジストリ登録時などにそうしたエラーが発生していませんか？

Comment: 管理者として、コンパイルやレジストリ登録は行っています。権限関係のエラーは起きていません。「SvrTest.exe」は、どこかに登録する必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: レジストリエディタでレジストリ内を検索して、それらのProgId(`TEST.clsCalc`や`SvrTest.SvrClass`)と、その参照先(`InprocServer32`のキー内に示されている情報)が存在するかどうかですね。存在しないのであれば、何か登録する作業が不足しているし、存在しているのであれば、何か呼び出し方に不足があるとかでは？

Comment: カンタンOLEサーバーの方のリンクの「SvrTest.exe」はダブルクリックして実行したら、自動的にレジストリに登録されました。ActiveXのEXEとはそういうものなのでしょうか？レジストリに登録されたので、サンプルについてはcreateObjectで参照できました。次は自分のプログラムで確認してみようと思います。

Comment: 上記はWindowsXP端末で実施しました。Windows10ではEXEの実行エラーになります。

Comment: 前のコメントに書いたように、管理者モードのコマンドプロンプトやコンテキストメニュー(右クリック)の管理者として実行で起動してみてください。

Comment: コンポーネントサービスのDCOMの構成にEXEに対応する16進数のようなプログラムIDの項目がありますが、これを消すにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 管理者モードコマンドプロンプトでこの記事 [26.3.4　レジストリへの登録と削除](http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/3020/30203D6240/USR20434.HTM) のように`/UnregServer`をパラメータに指定して実行すると削除できるかもしれません。出来ない場合はレジストリエディタを起動して手作業で1つ1つ探して削除する形になるでしょう。あとサービスとして登録・実行している場合は停止・削除してから行う必要があるようです。[UnregServerで削除できなくなったサービスを削除する方法](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/bbs/phpBB/viewtopic.php?topic=5821&forum=6)